# How to insert the current date into a file using abbrev or similar?

Tags: time-date, abbrev

I'd like to replicate something in emacs that I do in AutoHotkey all the time:

1. type `td`
2. have that string be replaced with the current date

I'm trying to do this with Emacs abbrevs but I'm running into an `Invalid function:` error.

I've also tried using a builtin function, but I get the same Invalid function error.  I've done a bunch of research but no avail.

Here's the code I have currently in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(defun insert-current-iso-date ()
    "..."
    (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d"))

(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table
  '(("td" "" (insert-current-iso-date))))
```

Comment: One can use `C-u M-! date -I` to insert a date, assuming GNU date, the prefix arg means insert the output of the shell command. I don't have experience with abbrev (it seems too heavy to me), so I'm not sure that's possible with Emacs' built-in abbrev, and I hear YASnippet is popular and powerful.

Comment: Related [Emacs Wiki - insert current date](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InsertingTodaysDate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the parenthesis from your custom function. It's calling for hook function name there, not its evaluation.

```lisp
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table
  '(("td" "" insert-current-iso-date)))
```

Anyway, to my understanding, you should define your abbrevs the way it's intended which is using `define-abbrev`, whose syntax is easier to follow, and not overriding the whole table definition unless you have a good reason to do so.

```lisp
(define-abbrev global-abbrev-table "td" "" 'insert-current-iso-date)
```

And, as @NickD pointed:

> you have to change the `insert-current-iso-date` to insert the string: it is not enough to return it as it does currently:
>
> ```lisp
> (defun insert-current-iso-date ()
>   (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d"))
> ```
>
> And of course you have to turn on abbrev-mode.

Comment: I think you also need to change the `insert-current-iso-date` to insert the formatted string: atm it just returns it.

Comment: @NickD Hook name calls to confusion, but it's all it needs as the symbol is defined. The hook is the function [`insert-current-iso-date`] for performing the expansion, so its return is what is inserted. Probably it should be named `current-iso-date` for clarity.

Comment: In my experiment, that did not work: `td` was replaced by an empty string; I had to explicitly insert - I didn't spend much time on it however, so I may very well be wrong.

Comment: I'd look further at the `define-abbrev` part

Comment: I have tested further: the hook has to insert the replacement string, it cannot just return it.

Comment: @NickD You're right. I started adding the insert, then retested without it, but forgot to reevaluate the hook. Checking `symbol-function` after your comment showed the bug. Then I misunderstood part of `insert-abbrev` code return with bugged code behavior.

Comment: Thank you all so much for this. I appreciate the rapid, accurate response, the back and forth about using insert, and the advice to use (define-abbrev). I was just trying to get it working, I'll now make it proper (eg. define-abbrev). I appreciate this, since 'td' is hard-coded into my muscle memory at this point and KNEW there would be a way to do it in Emacs! Thanks!!

Comment: Without good understanding of lisp, I just added this code (to replace what I had connected to `^Cd` before). It works, *except* calling `unexpand-abbrev` (just in case I actually need the string 'td'!) leaves `td2020-05-24` instead of just `td`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @StevePetersen Not sure of what's happening, I'd say you still had the previous abbrev loaded in the table, if not, please make a new question with all the details you can provide.

Comment: @NickMay You're welcome.